# having no knowledge to do the project that displaying countries and cities in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LgH4.png) So at the moment I'm trying to create an application where there's a two listbox, one shows the countries, one shows the cities in those countries. Having clicked the city in the listbox, the richtextbox will display the information in a specific format, which is the same as screenshot I provide. Then, the picturebox will provide the picture of that cities. There're also two labels: population and rainfall, which shows the statistics of it, but I don't know how to trigger that when I click the city in the listbox. Also, I want to know how to make the text font bigger and smaller by a checkbox, of course **BY CODE** . I'm currently working on codes, but it seems that I'm going nowhere.

```
Public Class frmWorldCities
    '---------------------------------------------------
    'Description: Class-wide declarations
    '
    'Calls: fNumOfFiles
    '---------------------------------------------------

    Const cstrPath As String = "..\Data\gldfiles\"
    Dim CIntNumofFiles As Integer = 78
    Dim cstrFileNames(CIntNumofFiles - 1) As String
    Dim cintFileLines(CIntNumofFiles - 1) As Integer
    Dim cstrCityNames(CIntNumofFiles - 1) As String
    Dim cstrFileCountryNames(CIntNumofFiles - 1) As String
    Dim cstrPopulation(CIntNumofFiles - 1) As String
    Dim cstrRainfall(CIntNumofFiles - 1) As String
    Dim cstrInformation(CIntNumofFiles - 1) As String
    Dim cstrPictureName(CIntNumofFiles - 1) As String

    Private Sub frmWorldCities_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        '---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        'Description: how the application should display while opening.
        '---------------------------------------------------------------------------

        Dim strTemp As String = ""
        Dim intLines As Integer
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer

        FileOpen(1, cstrPath & "list.wcf", OpenMode.Input)

        Input(1, strTemp)
            intLines = CInt(strTemp)

        For i = 0 To intLines - 2
            Input(1, cstrFileNames(i))
            lstCities.Items.Add(cstrFileNames(i))
        Next i
        FileClose(1)

        For i = 0 To cstrFileNames.Length - 1
            FileOpen(1, cstrPath & cstrFileNames(i), OpenMode.Input)
            Input(1, strTemp)
            cintFileLines(i) = CInt(strTemp)
            cstrCityNames(i) = LineInput(1)
            Input(1, strTemp)
            Input(1, cstrFileCountryNames(i))
            cstrPopulation(i) = LineInput(1)
            Input(1, cstrRainfall(i))
            Input(1, strTemp)

            For j = 0 To cintFileLines(i) - 10
                strTemp = LineInput(1)
                cstrInformation(i) &= strTemp & Chr(13)
            Next j

            Input(1, strTemp)
            Input(1, cstrPictureName(i))

            FileClose(1)
        Next i
    End Sub

    Private Sub lstCountries_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstCountries.SelectedIndexChanged
        '------------------------------------
        'Description: listing the cities.
        '------------------------------------
        Dim i As Integer
        lstCities.Items.Clear()

        For i = 0 To cstrCityNames.Length - 1
            If lstCountries.SelectedItem.ToString = cstrFileCountryNames(i) Then
                lstCities.Items.Add(cstrCityNames(i))
            End If
        Next i


    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        ' To close the application
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub chkBold_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkBold.CheckedChanged
        ' To make the information bold.
        If chkBold.Checked = True Then
            rtbInformation.Font = New Font(rtbInformation.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
        Else
            rtbInformation.Font = New Font(rtbInformation.Font, FontStyle.Regular)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub chkItalic_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkItalic.CheckedChanged
        If chkItalic.Checked = True Then
            rtbInformation.Font = New Font(rtbInformation.Font, FontStyle.Italic)
        Else
            rtbInformation.Font = New Font(rtbInformation.Font, FontStyle.Regular)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub chkBiggerFont_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkBiggerFont.CheckedChanged
        If chkBiggerFont.Checked = True Then
            rtbInformation.Font = New Font(rtbInformation.Font, FontStyle.Strikeout)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub chkSmallerFont_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkSmallerFont.CheckedChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles picCities.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: So where is the screenshot?

Comment: I'm just adding it.

Comment: First of all, don't ask multiple questions together. The bit about changing the font size is not relevant to the initial display of the data so does not belong here. As for the initial question, you do it all with data-binding. You should start by learning how data-binding works in WinForms and try it out with a single `ListBox` and the other controls. You can then add the second `ListBox` and implement [master/detail data-binding](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?518065).

Comment: Also, you really ought to avoid writing file I/O code like you were using VB6. `FileOpen` and anything related should be banished.

Comment: is it relate to data-binding? Cause I'm only learning about how to open data, I/O, and arrays.

Comment: can you tell specifically how it works?